# Quick question about the notation $\bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \cdots$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

My textbook is using the notation
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left [ 2 - \frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right]
$$
Does the comma here mean that the stuff inside the brackets represents a set? The set below is equivalent to the one above, right?
$$
\left\{ 2-\frac{1}{1}, 4+\frac{1}{1} \right\} \cup \left\{ 2-\frac{1}{2}, 4+\frac{1}{2}, \right\} \cup \dots \cup\left\{ 2-\frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right\} \cup \dots 
$$

Comment: Have you learned intervals?

Comment: No. Your set doesn't contain segments.

Comment: @Trebor Does the notation represent the *union* of intervals?

Comment: $\bigcup_{n=\Bbb{N}}$ or $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$?

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee It's supposed to be the latter, it's fixed now.

Comment: Not in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left [ 2 - \frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right] = \left\{x: \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in  \left [ 2 - \frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right]\right\}=\\=
\left[ 2-\frac{1}{1}, 4+\frac{1}{1} \right] \cup \left[ 2-\frac{1}{2}, 4+\frac{1}{2}, \right] \cup \dots \cup\left[ 2-\frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right] \cup \dots=[1,5]$$

Addition (may be you find this useful):
$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left [ 2 - \frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right] = \left\{x: \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in  \left [ 2 - \frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right]\right\}=\\=
\left[ 2-\frac{1}{1}, 4+\frac{1}{1} \right] \cap \left[ 2-\frac{1}{2}, 4+\frac{1}{2}, \right] \cap \dots \cap\left[ 2-\frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n} \right] \cap \dots=[2,4]$$

Answer (score 0):

$[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ is the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $a \le x \le b$. Can you use that to calculate the object your answer writes about? By the way, $(a,b)$ is the same but with $<$ instead of $\le$.